# Exposing assets in development and production in Rails 3.2

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3.2, asset-pipeline

I have a legacy Rails 3.2 app and if I have a JavaScript file at:

```
app/assets/javascripts/jt.js
```

I'm able to access it at

```
https://dev-platform.domain.com/assets/jt
```

We are using the asset pipeline and I'm not sure why this is available. It seems like something in `assets/javascripts` or `assets/styles` will show up. Is this the intended behavior? How can I prevent this?

Here's my Gemfile#assets

```
group :assets do
  gem 'coffee-rails', '3.2.2'
  gem 'font-awesome-sass', '4.7.0'
  gem 'foundation-rails', '6.1.2.0'
  gem 'jquery-rails', '3.1.4'
  gem 'jquery-ui-rails', '5.0.5'
  gem 'sass-rails', '3.2.6'
  gem 'turbo-sprockets-rails3', '0.3.14'
  gem 'twitter-bootstrap-rails', '2.2.8'
  gem 'uglifier', '2.7.2'
end
```

Comment: Have you set  config.assets.debug to true somewhere?

Comment: @ElChapo - nope, appreciate help. I know a legacy version

Comment: I have a legacy app too, and i was able to replicate your issue

Comment: If i set config.assets.compile = true, i am able to access the assets as you say

Comment: Setting it to false makes them no longer accessible, can you give this a try?

Comment: so this might be the issue - the strange thing is that we also have some unminified files that cause an error.